# How to limit access to mulesoft API resources based on users?

Tags: api, resources, policy, anypoint-platform

How to apply a resource-level policy based on the client who is accessing the resource?
Like, imagine Instagram, I want a user to be able to access users/{userId}/posts, but only his posts, no other user's posts. I tried with client I'd enforcement, but can't figure it out, it always skips the validation. Is there any policy for this purpose? Or do I have to create a custom one? And if so, what are the steps to follow?

Answer (score 0):

Resource level policies need to be setup correctly by following the instructions [in the documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/resource-level-policies-about).

What you need is authorization, not authentication. Probably you need to implement your custom policy because the existing policies don't know about your resource management (ie which posts belong to which user).